# Unmarshal json to reflected struct

Tags: json, go, reflection, unmarshalling

Is it possible to unmarshal JSON into a struct made from reflection without hardcoding the original type?

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "encoding/json"
  "reflect"
)

type Employee struct {
  Firstname string     `json:"firstname"`
}

func main() {
  //Original struct
  orig := new(Employee)

  t := reflect.TypeOf(orig)
  v := reflect.New(t.Elem())

  //Reflected struct
  new := v.Elem().Interface().(Employee)

  // Unmarshal to reflected struct
  json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"firstname\": \"bender\"}"), &new)

  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", new)
}
```

I used a cast to `Employee` in this example. But what if i don't know the type?

When i just use `v` for the unmarhaling the struct will be zeroed.

```
json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"firstname\": \"bender\"}"), v)
```

When I omit the cast I get a map. which is understandable

```
json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"firstname\": \"bender\"}"), v.Elem().Interface())
```

Comment: Just because it's something that really hurt my eyes: why do you have a var called `new`? And what's the point of your using `new(Employee)` over the more flexible `&Employee{}`?

Comment: new(Something) is better than &Something{}. It is consistent with non-struct types + it is for that job.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is that if you omit the type assertion here:

```
new := v.Elem().Interface()
```

The `new` is inferred to have a `interface{}` type.

Then when you take the address to unmarshal, the type of `&new` is `*interface{}` (pointer to interface{}) and unmarshal does not work as you expect.

You can avoid the type assertion if instead of getting the `Elem()` you work directly with the pointer reference.

```
func main() {
  //Original struct
  orig := new(Employee)

  t := reflect.TypeOf(orig)
  v := reflect.New(t.Elem())

  // reflected pointer
  newP := v.Interface()

  // Unmarshal to reflected struct pointer
  json.Unmarshal([]byte("{\"firstname\": \"bender\"}"), newP)

  fmt.Printf("%+v\n", newP)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/lTBU-1PqM4

Answer (score 3):

```
// https://github.com/xiaojun207/go-base-utils/blob/master/utils/Clone.go
func NewInterface(typ reflect.Type, data []byte) interface{} {
    if typ.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        typ = typ.Elem()
        dst := reflect.New(typ).Elem()
        json.Unmarshal(data, dst.Addr().Interface())
        return dst.Addr().Interface()
    }else {
        dst := reflect.New(typ).Elem()
        json.Unmarshal(data, dst.Addr().Interface())
        return dst.Interface()
    }
}

type Employee struct {
    Firstname string     `json:"firstname"`
}

func main() {
    data := "{\"firstName\": \"John\"}"
    obj := NewInterface(reflect.TypeOf(Employee{}), []byte(data))
    fmt.Println("Employee:", obj)
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the type at all, you can Unmarshal the JSON string into an interface{}. If you then need to work with the Unmarshaled data, you can convert it to the desired type.

Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
    "unsafe"
)

type Employee struct {
    Firstname string `json:"firstName"`
}

func deserialize(jsonData string) interface{} {
    var obj interface{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonData), &obj); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    return obj
}

func NewEmployee(objData map[string]interface{}) *Employee {
    s := (*Employee)(nil)
    t := reflect.TypeOf(s).Elem()
    employeePtr := reflect.New(t)
    employee := (*Employee)(unsafe.Pointer(employeePtr.Pointer()))
    employee.Firstname = objData["firstName"].(string)

    return employee
}

func main() {
    jsonData := "{\"firstName\": \"John\"}"

    obj := deserialize(jsonData)

    objData := obj.(map[string]interface{})
    employee := NewEmployee(objData)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", employee.Firstname)
}
```

You can check it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/B0bgfB4-uv).